# How to show sum of values of chid in parent c# dataTreeListView

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

may i know how to show sum of the child in parent in c# dataTreeListView

i have shared a screen shot [image]

i wish to know how to show 5000 in person A which is sum of child table and the parent table can any one please help me

i want to do this on c# object listview

what i done to get above tree is

on form load i wrote this code

```
List<Class1> list = new List<Class1>();
                list = Class1.GetList();
                this.dataTreeListView2.ParentKeyAspectName = "ParentId";
                this.dataTreeListView2.RootKeyValueString = "1";
                BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn col = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn();
                col.Width = 10;
                dataTreeListView2.DataSource = list;
                foreach (ColumnHeader column in this.dataTreeListView2.Columns)
                {
                    column.Width = 100 + 100+ this.dataTreeListView2.SmallImageSize.Width;
                }
                this.dataTreeListView2.Columns.RemoveByKey("Id");
                this.dataTreeListView2.Columns.RemoveByKey("ParentId");
```

and

class1.cs file has

```
namespace bbcon_accout_software
{
    class Class1
    {
        /*public string Name { get; set;}
        public Double Value { get; set; }
        public List<Double> Children {get; set;}*/
        protected string xName;
        protected string xId;
        protected string xParentId;
        protected decimal xcredit;
        protected decimal xdebit;
        public Class1()
        {
            //Name = name;
            //Value = value;
            //Children = new List<Double>();
            //Children.Add(2);
            //Children.Add(3);
            this.xName = "";
            this.xId = "";
            this.xParentId = "";
            this.xcredit = 0.0M;
            this.xdebit = 0.0M;
        }
        public String Name1
        {
            get { return this.xName; }
            set { this.xName = value; }
        }

        public String Id
        {
            get { return this.xId; }
            set { this.xId = value; }
        }

        public String ParentId
        {
            get { return this.xParentId; }
            set { this.xParentId = value; }
        }

        public Decimal Credit
        {
            get { return this.xcredit; }
            set { this.xcredit = value; }
        }

        public Decimal Debit
        {
            get { return this.xdebit; }
            set { this.xdebit = value; }
        }
        public static List<Class1> GetList()
        {
            List<Class1> oList = new List<Class1>();
            Class1 oClass4 = new Class1();
            oClass4.Name1 = "Person A";
            oClass4.Id = "xyz";
            oClass4.ParentId = "1";
            oClass4.Credit = 1;
            oClass4.Debit = 1000;
            oList.Add(oClass4);
            Class1 oClass1 = new Class1();
            oClass1.Name1 = "Person B";
            oClass1.Id = "ldc";
            oClass1.ParentId = "xyz";
            oClass1.Credit = 1;
            oClass1.Debit = 2000;
            oList.Add(oClass1);
            Class1 oClass2 = new Class1();
            oClass2.Name1 = "Person C";
            oClass2.Id = "ccc";
            oClass2.ParentId = "xyz";
            oClass2.Credit = 1;
            oClass2.Debit = 1000;
            oList.Add(oClass2);
            Class1 oClass5 = new Class1();
            oClass5.Name1 = "Person A";
            oClass5.Id = "mno";
            oClass5.ParentId = "xyz";
            oClass5.Credit = 1;
            oClass5.Debit = 1000;
            oList.Add(oClass5);
            return oList;
        }
    }
}
```

please help me to do this

in tag section of question i added objectlistview but i want to show details on
dataTreeListview

Comment: Person A is a child Of person A,  so shouldn't the sum actually be 4000?

Comment: @johnny5  yes sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to filter by the parent and then sum the list like so:

```
public static float SumChildren(string parentKey){
    return GetList().Where(x => x.ParentId == parentKey).Sum(x => x.Debit)
}
```

You may have to switch the return type, but I'm assuming Debit is a decimal

Based on your comments your code requires a bigger refactor. You should be adding the data through a method and have that method update the parent debit value based off of the children added.

But As a quick hack you can just assign the parent value, but if you're going to do this for multi-nest trees you'll need to start at the deepest branch and work your way up.

```
var parentDebitValue = SumChildren("xyz");
GetList().Where(x => x.Id == "xyz").First().Debit = parentDebitValue;
```

But realisticly you should re achitect your program

Comment: when i tried above code on class1.cs i get an error Error 1 Member 'bbcon_accout_software.Class1.GetList()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @shahidkhan sorry didn't see it was a static list, remove this this and make the method static.  I've edited the answer

Comment: @jhonny 5 thanks for replay and error is gone but sorry this is not what i like to get i mean to get sum on same dataTreeListview.


like 4000 on top of tree

Comment: @shahidkhan you're architecture is messed up you should add have a method to add your class and update the value when added, or an event etc,  but you can do that as a hack for now, please remember to upvote and mark as correct if this satisfies you're question

Comment: @jhonny  5   i did't get the correct result but i got the logic. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help